# CTCI Chapter 1 : Palindrome Permutation

Tags: python, palindrome

Below is my code for the problem 1.4 in CTCI. I would like a review of my code and if my approach to the problem is correct.

**Problem Statement:** 
Palindrome Permutation: Given a string, write a function to check if it is a permutation of
a palindrome. A palindrome is a word or phrase that is the same forwards and backwards. A
permutation is a rearrangement of letters. The palindrome does not need to be limited to just
dictionary words.

EXAMPLE

Input: Tact Coa

Output: True (permutations:"taco cat'; "atco cta'; etc.)

My Solution (Python):

```
def checkPalindromeAndPermutation(inputstr):
    lengthOfInputString = len(inputstr)
    counterforodd = 0
    actualCharactersInInput = 0
    inputstr = inputstr.lower()
    hashTable = dict()

    for i in inputstr:
        if i != " ":
            hashTable[i] = hashTable.get(i, 0) + 1
            actualCharactersInInput = actualCharactersInInput + 1
    print(hashTable)

    for item in hashTable:
        # if input has even length, but each character's frequency is not even, then it's not a plaindrome
        if actualCharactersInInput % 2 == 0 and hashTable[item] % 2 != 0: 
            return False
        # if input has odd length, but more than one character's frequency is greater than 1 , then it's not a plaindrome
        if actualCharactersInInput % 2 == 1 and hashTable[item] % 2 == 1:
            counterforodd = counterforodd + 1
            if counterforodd > 1:
                return False
    return True


print("Answer : " , checkPalindromeAndPermutation("abc bac"))
```

Comment: The logic can be simplified.  You only need to verify that at most 1 character has an odd count.

Answer (score 7):

Nice implementation.

Here are a couple suggestions

#### collections.defaultdict

Intead of `hashTable[i] = hashTable.get(i, 0) + 1`, use `collections.defaultdict`

```
charcount = defaultdict(int)

for char in inputStr:
    charcount[char] += 1
actualCharactersInInput = len(inputStr) - charcount[' ']
```

#### collections.Counter

Or better yet, use a Counter:

```
charcount = collections.Counter(inputStr)
actualCharactersInInput = len(inputStr) - charcount[' ']
```

#### other

```
if actualCharactersInInput % 2:
    # odd number of chars
    return sum(count%2 for count in charcount.values()) == 1
else:
    # even number of chars
    return not any(count % 2 for count in charcount.values())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I learned something new today :)

Comment: You can "smarten" the final check. If the length is odd there must be 1 character with an odd frequency. If the length is even there must be 0 characters with an odd frequency. Change `not any(count % 2 for count in charcount.values())` to `sum(count%2 for count in charcount.values()) == 0`. Then the check is one line `return sum(count%2 for count in charcount.values()) == actualCharactersInInput % 2`

Comment: @spyr03, I thought of that too, but opted to use `not any(...)` because it would stop when it found the first odd count rather than `sum` the entire list.  Probably a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 4):

This looks correct! Here are my thoughts on the code:

- Per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), use `snake_case` for variable names and `PascalCase` for class names.
- Use Python builtins. Python makes frequency counting effortless using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).
- Unused variable: `lengthOfInputString`. A static code analysis tool like a linter can spot this.
- Avoid variable names like `hashMap`. Something like `freq_count`, `seen` or `char_count` is clearer.
- Avoid using `i` as the loop block variable in `for i in enumerable:`. Reserve `i` for index variables and prefer something like `c` or `elem` that describes the variable more accurately.
- The function name, `checkPalindromeAndPermutation`, doesn't accurately describe what the function does, long as it is. I prefer `is_palindrome_permutation` or `palindrome_permutation`.
- Remove all `print` statements from your functions to avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).
- While I'm not a fan of inline comments, the comments in this program explain the logic nicely (typo and horizontal scrolling aside). Consider moving them to the function docstring, though, which summarizes the entire function neatly and gets out of the way of the code.
- `actualCharactersInInput` can be replaced with `len(s)` assuming you don't mind stripping whitespace beforehand. Having a separate cached variable for holding `len()` is generally poor practice because the overhead of the function call is worth it to improve readability and reduce the risk of subtle bugs (`len()` and cached value going out of sync).
- Use `foo += 1` instead of `foo = foo + 1` to increment an integer.
- Branching inside the `for` loop doesn't make much sense since the length of `actualCharactersInInput` is fixed. It makes more sense to pick a branch and stick to it as a human might do naturally if performing this task by hand.

  Instead of:

  ```
  for item in hashTable:
      if actualCharactersInInput % 2 == 0 and hashTable[item] % 2 != 0: 
          ...
      elif actualCharactersInInput % 2 == 1 and hashTable[item] % 2 == 1:
      #^^^ we can use elif since the conditional is disjoint
          ...
  ```

  try:

  ```
  if actualCharactersInInput % 2 == 0:
      for item in hashTable:
          if hashTable[item] % 2 != 0:
              ...
  else:
      for item in hashTable:
          if hashTable[item] % 2 == 1:
              ...
  ```

  Luckily, [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/) will make the performance impact negligible even if we apply the conditional inside the loop, so this is mostly about reducing cognitive load on the programmer and isn't a hard-line rule.

---

Here's a possible re-write:

```
from collections import Counter

def permuted_palindrome(s):
    s = "".join(s.lower().split())
    odds = [x for x in Counter(s).values() if x % 2]

    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return len(odds) < 1

    return len(odds) < 2
```

This can cause a performance drop because of a lack of early return option. Benchmark the impact and make a call of performance vs brevity based on your use case.

---

I recommend validating correctness on any algorithm that's easily written using a clear-cut brute force method:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations
from random import randint as rnd

def permuted_palindrome(s):
    ''' 
    Determines if a string is a permuted palindrome.
    A string is a permuted palindrome if:
      1. the string is of odd length and has 1 or fewer
         characters with an odd number of occurrences.
      - or - 
      2. the string is of even length and has no 
         characters with an odd number of occurrences.

    >>> permuted_palindrome("aaa")
    True
    >>> permuted_palindrome("aaab")
    False
    >>> permuted_palindrome("aaaab")
    True
    >>> permuted_palindrome("aaaabc")
    False
    >>> permuted_palindrome("aaaabcc")
    True
    '''
    s = "".join(s.lower().split())
    odds = [x for x in Counter(s).values() if x % 2]

    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return len(odds) < 1

    return len(odds) < 2

def brute_permuted_palindrome(s):
    return any(x == x[::-1] for x in permutations("".join(s.lower().split())))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests = 1000
    passes = 0

    for x in range(tests):
        s = "".join(chr(rnd(65, 70)) for x in range(rnd(1, 10)))

        if brute_permuted_palindrome(s) == permuted_palindrome(s):
            passes += 1

    print(f"passed {passes}/{tests} tests")
```

Randomization doesn't guarantee perfect coverage, but it's an easy way to be pretty certain your code works and can often catch edge cases that might be overlooked in enumeration (best to do both).

This snippet also shows how you might include a full docstring with doctests and uses the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard which makes your module easily importable.

Comment: Waow, Thank you for a detailed explanation. This is very helpful.

Comment: Why ` s = "".join(s.lower().split())` instead of `s.lower()` or `s.casefold()`. And if you do `odds = sum(x % 2 for x in Counter(s).values())`,you don't need the len, and can do `return odds < 1 + (len(s) % 2)`

Comment: You can reduce the return logic to `return len(odds) == len(s) % 2`. Even length strings can have no odds, while odd length strings can have one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. `s = "".join(s.lower().split())` removes whitespace and lowers the string. After removing whitespace, the rest of the logic is much cleaner, and this handles more than just spaces. I kept `len` over `sum` because `sum` seemed to obfuscate the logic a bit. `return len(odds) == len(s) % 2` seems reasonable but I think going terser at this point has diminishing returns.

Answer (score 1):

Revised from my C# version
Using a set instead of a dictionary or hashtable uses less space
We casefold to ignore case sensitivity and then by sorting this we can try to fail out early. If we have any more than 2 odd letters (which will happen any time we check a third unique char) then we fail out.  But we don't want to fail when checking the second member, because it could possibly be removed.
If we didn't fail early we still want to make sure we have at most one odd letter. Therefore the final boolean comparison returns appropriately.

```py
    def isPermutedPalindrome(input_string):      
      if (len(input_string) < 2):
        return True
      input_string = sorted(input_string.casefold())

      char_set = set()
      for letter in input_string:
        if letter == ' ':
          continue
        if letter in char_set:
          char_set.remove(letter)
        else:
          char_set.add(letter)
        if (len(char_set) > 2):
          return False
      return (len(char_set) < 2)
```

Comment: When answering a question, you should at least try to review the original code in some way or another. Answering in a different language is also confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure how to do it in Python right away, so here's the converted snippet.

Comment: Thank's for taking the time to convert the snippet. Could you also explain the differences between your snippet and OP code to make us understand why your solution could be better?

Comment: In python, a `set` would be a more natural datastructure for this `char_list` than a list. And the `letter is ' '` only works because CPython interns a number of strings that occur a lot. `letter == ' '` is more universally correct

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone!